# Storing blocks in a c-style array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to dynamically instantiate a c array of blocks, load it and then run them and could use some help.

```
// Definitions ===========================================
typedef void (^MorphC)(ScratchC* scratch);

@property (nonatomic) MorphC __strong * morphCs;

// Building up the Morph Registry ========================
static NSMutableDictionary* morphs_;
+ (void) initialize {
    morphs_ = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [MathC hydrate];
}
+ (void) hydrate {  
    [MathC registerMorph:@"sin" execute:^(ScratchC* scratch) {
        AEScratchPush(scratch, sin(AEScratchPop(scratch)));
    }];
}
+ (void) registerMorph:(NSString*)name execute:(MorphC)execute {
    [morphs_ setObject:execute forKey:name];
}
+ (MorphC) morphFromKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [morphs_ objectForKey:key];
}


// Loading up a temporary NSMutableArray* _compiling =====
- (void) applyTag:(NSString*)tag stack:(Stack*)stack {
    [_compiling addObject:[MathC morphFromKey:tag]];
}

// Initializing C Array and loading from NSMutableArray ==
- (void) build {
    _morphCs = (MorphC __strong *)malloc(_compiling.count*sizeof(MorphC));
    i = 0;
    for (MorphC morph in _compiling)
        _morphCs[i++] = morph;              // Currently, getting a bad ACCESS here
}

// Executing the Morphs ==================================
- (CGFloat) evaluateFloat:(VarsC*)vars {
    if (![_morphs count]) return NAN;
    AEScratchLoadVariables(_scratch, vars);

    for (int i=0;i<[_morphs count];i++)
        _morphCs[i](_scratch);

    return AEScratchPop(_scratch);
}
```

I'm currently getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS while building up the C Array, but I suspect I have a number of issues.  I don't totally understand the need for the __strong at the morphCs definition, but the compiler complains with out.  Should the property have a strong indicator also?

Do I need to be doing [morph copy] in one or more places?

Is there anything else I'm messing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `malloc` an array of strong pointers.

Think about the semantics of a strong pointer: When it is declared, it's value is initialized to nil. When the variable goes out of scope, it releases its existing value. Therefore, the compiler must be able to keep track of strong pointers to be able to carry this out. If you have an array of strong pointers of unknown length, when it goes out of scope for example, how can the compiler know how many pointers to release? It can't.

In C++ terminology, strong references are "non-POD" types - they have nontrivial constructors and destructors. Therefore, they cannot be allocated with `malloc`.

It is mentioned [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#conversion-of-pointers-to-ownership-qualified-types) in the ARC specification:

> It is undefined behavior if a managed operation is performed on a
>   __strong or __weak object without a guarantee that it contains a primitive zero bit-pattern, or if the storage for such an object is
>   freed or reused without the object being first assigned a null
>   pointer.

In other words, the only way you can use `malloc` and `free` is if you guarantee that every time after you call `malloc` you zero the memory of all the pointers you allocated, before using them. And every time before `free` you guarantee to first assign `nil` to each strong pointer in the array.

However, in Objective-C++, you *can* use `new[]` and `delete[]` to dynamically allocate arrays of strong pointers.

> These requirements are followed automatically in Objective-C++ when
>   creating objects of retainable object owner type with new or new[] and
>   destroying them with delete, delete[], or a pseudo-destructor
>   expression.

Comment: so the solution is `calloc`?

Comment: @BryanChen: `calloc` should work. (plus the setting pointers to `nil` before `free`ing; he doesn't show where he `free`s in his code)

Comment: I actually was able to get this working by setting the pointers to __weak.  Can I simply set it to __weak and handle the memory management myself?  I also added a 'copy' to the registerMorph method, but no where else.  This combination now seems to be working fine.  But, I really am pretty uneasy about what is actually going on.

Comment: @aepryus: `__weak` is also a non-POD type, and it is also required to be initialized to `nil`. ARC does a lot of stuff with `__weak`. Only `__unsafe_unretained` is not managed by ARC. Anyway, does zeroing the memory not work?

Comment: @aepryus: As for the copy, do you mean something like `[morphs_ setObject:[execute copy] forKey:name];`? I have had heated arguments on StackOverflow where I have argued that the ARC specification does not guarantee a copy in this case, so an explicit copy is needed according to the spec. Regardless, the current ARC compilers should add a copy in this case, so it would be weird if not having a copy caused you any problems.

Comment: @newacct I will experiment with these questions today.  However, with the array set to __weak and with the copy being used to insert into the NSDictionary everything seems to be working as expected.  Before I added the copy, I was getting memory overwrite type behavior.  (i.e., in the debugger, object data types were incorrect and eventually would get a EXE_BAD_ACCCESS error)

Comment: @newacct yes, [morphs_ setObject:[execute copy] forKey:name] is exactly what I am using.  I'm converting this library from Objective-C objects to C for performance reasons.  I'll experiment, but would you expect __unsafe_unretained to have sizable performance gains?

Comment: @aepryus: But `__unsafe_unretained` is not correct. When you store a pointer to an object for use later after the current call, it must be retained.